# How to assert JSON value?

Tags: java, json, spring, testing

Given the following JSON that is returned from a REST call:

```
{"Statistik Eintraege":
[{"Wert":"1","Anzahl":41},
{"Wert":"","Anzahl":482},
{"Wert":"-3","Anzahl":1},
{"Wert":"-1","Anzahl":3},
{"Wert":"-2","Anzahl":3}],
"Statistik Typ":"BlahStatistik"}
```

... I want to verify the 'Anzahl' of Wert='' that is in this example: 482.

What I tried in my java integration test is:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl", hasSize(482)));
```

The exception:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl"
    Expected: a collection with size <482>
         but: collection size was <1>
```

What else could I try?

Comment: I don't know but I'm sure `hasSize` isn't the correct assertion and is the direct cause of your error. Don't you have some `isEqualTo` or similar?

Comment: Indeed, `hasSize` checks if there's an array there which has 482 values, not if you have a number with the value 482.

Comment: I tried: .andExpect(jsonPath("$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl", equalTo(482))); and it seems to be better: java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl"
Expected: <482>
     but: was <[482]>   So better, but not solved yet...

Comment: solved it by: .andExpect(jsonPath("$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl").value(482));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl").value(482));
```

But why does the following:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$..[?(@.Wert == '')].Anzahl", greaterThan(400)))
```

throw an error?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (net.minidev.json.JSONArray is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```